# How to load GUSE v1 with Tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to load [Google Universal Sentence Encoder v1](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1) with Tensorflow 2.4.1. GUSE v4 loads fine with tensorflow 2, and GUSE v1 loads with tensorflow 1, but unfortunately I need to run experiments with GUSE v1 using tensorflow 2 if possible.

First I tried:

```
>>> import tensorflow_hub as hub
>>> guse_v1 = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1")
```

which gave lots of warnings, and then

```
>>> guse_v1(["This is a sentence.",])
```

failed with

```
TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable
```

I googled this error and found https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_issues which lead me to try:

```
>>> guse_v1.signatures["default"](["This is a sentence.",])
```

which resulted in

```
TypeError: pruned(sentence): expected argument #0(zero-based) to be a Tensor; got list (['This is a sentence.'])
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix this, but after some more digging I found https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/model_compatibility so I tried:

```
>>> guse_v1 = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1", signature="default")
>>> guse_v1(["This is a sentence.",])
```

But this still fails with

```
TypeError: pruned(sentence): expected argument #0(zero-based) to be a Tensor; got list (['This is a sentence.'])
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work with

```
import tensorflow as tf
guse_v1.signatures["default"](tf.constant(["This is a sentence."]))
```